# How to access a xsd file inside webcontent folder from normal java class?

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, xsd

I have a war file which is deployed on tomcat server. This war has xsd file at location   webcontent -> WEB-INF -> resources -> HumanActivitySchema.xsd

I have a java class which is trying to load the schema to validate the input xml structure. This java class is part of war file deployment.

My java code function  looks like:

```
public boolean validateXMLSchema(String iActivity){


    Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("HumanActivitySchema.xsd"));

    try {
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(iActivity)));
    }
    catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
        if(DBG){
            System.out.println("Error Message while validating activity : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But the issue with this code is, it is not finding xsd file. So all fields of schemaFile are null. As a result exception is thrown at **factory.newSchema(schemaFile)** point.

Can  anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and what changes I should do so that I can load my .xsd file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two alternatives:

1. Put your XSD in on the classpath by placing it in the WEB-INF/classes directory, and load it with:

   getClass().getClassLoader()
           .getResourceAsStream("/HumanActivitySchema.xsd")

   Note the preceding slash ('/'). You can also place it in a folder matching the package name of your Java class, and the omit the preceding '/'.
2. Read the XSD through the [ServletContext#getResourceAsStrem(String path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) method. In your case the path would be

   /HumanActivitySchema.xsd

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I used your 1st solution and as said places xsd file inside WEB-INF/classes directory. And it worked for me. Thanks a lot! :)